# How can I add the Bootstrap package to my meteor app?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I thought maybe bootstrap was added by default to new meteor apps; to attempt to verify that, I used:

```
C:\Meteor\scheduler>meteor list
```

...and it returned:

```
autopublish      1.0.3  Publish the entire database to all clients
insecure         1.0.3  Allow all database writes by default
meteor-platform  1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages in you...
```

So what's in meteor-platform? I tried:

```
C:\Meteor\scheduler>meteor show meteor-platform
```

...and got:

```
Package: meteor-platform@1.2.2
Maintainers: mdg
Implies: blaze, check, ddp, deps, ejson, fastclick (web.cordova), jquery,
         launch-screen (web.browser, web.cordova), livedata, logging,
         meteor, mobile-status-bar (web.cordova), mongo, random, session,
         spacebars, templating, tracker, ui, underscore, webapp

This package is added to every app by `meteor create`. It includes a set
of common packages that most Meteor apps will find useful, such as
`webapp`, `tracker`, `session`, `ddp`, `mongo` and `blaze`. From the
command line, you can run `meteor show meteor-platform` to see the full
list of implied packages.

These packages make up the official [Meteor
Platform](https://www.meteor.com/projects). See the README of each
individual package to learn more about it.

This package was previously known as
[standard-app-packages](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/standard-app-packages).

Recent versions:
  1.1.1  September 25th, 2014
  1.1.2  October 13th, 2014
  1.2.0  October 28th, 2014
  1.2.1  December 19th, 2014
  1.2.2  March 17th, 2015      installed

Older and pre-release versions of meteor-platform have been hidden. To see
all 49 versions, run 'meteor show --show-all meteor-platform'.
```

So, I tried the "show-all" command and got:

```
Package: meteor-platform@1.2.2
Maintainers: mdg
Implies: blaze, check, ddp, deps, ejson, fastclick (web.cordova), jquery,
         launch-screen (web.browser, web.cordova), livedata, logging,
         meteor, mobile-status-bar (web.cordova), mongo, random, session,
         spacebars, templating, tracker, ui, underscore, webapp

This package is added to every app by `meteor create`. It includes a set
of common packages that most Meteor apps will find useful, such as
`webapp`, `tracker`, `session`, `ddp`, `mongo` and `blaze`. From the
command line, you can run `meteor show meteor-platform` to see the full
list of implied packages.

These packages make up the official [Meteor
Platform](https://www.meteor.com/projects). See the README of each
individual package to learn more about it.

This package was previously known as
[standard-app-packages](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/standard-app-packages).

Versions:
  0.0.0-glasser-isopacket.0  November 6th, 2014
  0.0.1                      August 29th, 2014
  1.0.1-glasser1             September 4th, 2014
  1.0.1-rc0                  August 28th, 2014
  1.0.1-rc1                  September 1st, 2014
  1.0.1                      September 4th, 2014
  1.0.2                      September 6th, 2014
  1.0.3-ekate                September 11th, 2014
  1.1.0-rc0                  September 2nd, 2014
  1.1.0-rc1                  September 9th, 2014
  1.1.0-rc2                  September 10th, 2014
  1.1.0                      September 15th, 2014
  1.1.1-rc0                  September 19th, 2014
  1.1.1                      September 25th, 2014
  1.1.2-nim.1                October 8th, 2014
  1.1.2-pre.0                September 30th, 2014
  1.1.2-pre.1                October 1st, 2014
  1.1.2-pre.2                October 1st, 2014
  1.1.2-pre.3                October 3rd, 2014
  1.1.2-pre.4                October 3rd, 2014
  1.1.2-rc.0                 October 7th, 2014
  1.1.2-refreshpolicy.1      October 17th, 2014
  1.1.2                      October 13th, 2014
  1.2.0-rc.0                 October 17th, 2014
  1.2.0-win.0                November 17th, 2014
  1.2.0                      October 28th, 2014
  1.2.1-eachin.0             March 1st, 2015
  1.2.1-ipc.0                November 22nd, 2014
  1.2.1-rc.1                 December 11th, 2014
  1.2.1-slava.0              January 8th, 2015
  1.2.1-win.0                December 1st, 2014
  1.2.1-winr.0               December 18th, 2014
  1.2.1-winr.1               January 20th, 2015
  1.2.1-winr.2               January 20th, 2015
  1.2.1-winr.3               January 20th, 2015
  1.2.1                      December 19th, 2014
  1.2.2-eachin.43            March 1st, 2015
  1.2.2-githubble.0          February 16th, 2015
  1.2.2-githubble.1          February 16th, 2015
  1.2.2-githubble.42         February 16th, 2015
  1.2.2-githubble.43         February 16th, 2015
  1.2.2-rc.0                 March 5th, 2015
  1.2.2-winr.0               January 13th, 2015
  1.2.2-winr.1               January 14th, 2015
  1.2.2-winr.3               February 24th, 2015
  1.2.2                      March 17th, 2015      installed
  1.2.3-galaxy.0             July 17th, 2015
  1.2.3-plugins.0            July 22nd, 2015
  1.2.3-rc.0                 August 10th, 2015
```

No bootstrap anywhere, so I tried:

```
C:\Meteor\scheduler> meteor add bootstrap
```

...but it errored out with "no such package"

So...how can I add the Bootstrap package to my meteor app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` to add the pre-compiled bootstrap css to your project.

If you are going to be using LESS instead and would like to be able to have more control over how and when bootstrap is compiled and linked to you application, I would recommend using a combination of the LESS plugin (`meteor add less`) and the custom bootstrap package, `meteor add nemo64:bootstrap`. Review the documentation for the latter [here](https://github.com/Nemo64/meteor-bootstrap/).

If you need to use other frameworks or libraries out there, you can always check the [atmospherejs](https://atmospherejs.com/) community to see if a meteor package already exists and how to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I see GPicazo is on it. I agree just type in meteor add twbs:bootstrap. Also https://atmospherejs.com/ is a great place to find packages. You might even find some you would like for your current project or a future one.

Answer (score 1):

Any questions you might have about Meteor packages in general, will be answered in a second by going here https://atmospherejs.com

Answer (score 1):

You can add it with 
meteor add twbs:bootstrap

and then you can write bootstrap code in your javascript/css/html like normal. Its that simple.